# How get an apostrophe in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some stuff with javascript and I'm wondering, how do I put an apostrophe in a string in javascript?

```
theAnchorText = 'I apostrophe M home';
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
theAnchorText = "I'm home";
```

Alternatively, escape the apostrophe:

```
theAnchorText = 'I\'m home';
```

The backslash tells JavaScript (this has nothing to do with jQuery, by the way) that the next character should be interpreted as "special". In this case, an apostrophe after a backslash means to use a literal apostrophe but not to end the string.

There are also other characters you can put after a backslash to indicate other special characters. For example, you can use `\n` for a new line, or `\t` for a tab.

Answer (score 12):

You can try the following:

```
theAnchorText = "I'm home";
```

OR

```
theAnchorText = 'I\'m home';
```

Answer (score 11):

This is plain Javascript and has nothing to do with the jQuery library.

You simply escape the apostrophe with a backslash:

```
theAnchorText = 'I\'m home';
```

Another alternative is to use quotation marks around the string, then you don't have to escape apostrophes:

```
theAnchorText = "I'm home";
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put an apostrophe in a single quoted JavaScript string by escaping it with a backslash, like so:

`theAnchorText = 'I\'m home';`