# HTML button doesn't do anything and unexpected code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple don't press the button game and there are two errors (the other will be in a different question)
Unexpected text
this is the code I wrote:

```
<body>
        <h1>Don't press the button</h1><br/>
        <p>DON'T PRESS THE BUTTON</p>
        <div class="round-button">
          <button type="button" onclick="alert('Why Did You Press Me. The next button you click will have consequences')">Don't Click Me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="hint-text">
          <p><b>V V V V</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="round-button button2">
          <button type="button" onclick="alert('Ok, this is your last chance. Don't press anymore buttons... not that there are any')">NOT A BUTTON</button>
        </div>
```

and this is the code in the web page:

```html
<body>
        "Don't Press the Button "
        <h1>Don't press the button</h1><br/>
        <p>DON'T PRESS THE BUTTON</p>
        <div class="round-button">
          <button type="button" onclick="alert('Why Did You Press Me. The next button you click will have consequences')">Don't Click Me</button>
        </div>
        <div class="hint-text">
          <p><b>V V V V</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="round-button button2">
          <button type="button" onclick="alert('Ok, this is your last chance. Don't press anymore buttons... not that there are any')">NOT A BUTTON</button>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please review [ask] and edit your question to include the necessary context, as well as to properly format your code so that others can read it.

Comment: All we want is the html and javascript code.

Comment: "*there is two errors 1. Unexpected text*" Ok, *what* text? What's the second issue? Why haven't you included this context fully?

Comment: i accidentally submitted before i was done sorry

Comment: it doesn't show my code it just runs it in the question

Comment: That would be because you didn't read the formatting instructions carefully enough, didn't use the live demo button in the question editor, and overwrote my edit where I fixed it for you.

Comment: @Quentin sorry, didn't realize someone edited it, also what "live demo button"

Comment: There aren't very many buttons. Hover them. Read the tooltips.

Comment: You have an apostrophe in "Don't", that is causing the problem.  You need to escape it with `\'`

Comment: @KScandrett provided the explanation.  You can use double quotes or single quotes to designate strings, but you need to make sure that the content between the quotes doesn't contain same character.  If it does, you need to escape it, as he showed.

Comment: Ok thanks @gview I didn't realize that was there, I added the break, and it all works fine now

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257619/how-get-an-apostrophe-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Cryptic, don't forget to open  the console (press F12 and click on console tab) when you have errors. The error message "missing ) after argument list is because a ')' was expected after the `'` in `don't`.

Answer (score 0):

As @K Scandrett said in their comment, the apostrophe in "Don't" is causing your problem. You need to escape it by putting a "" before, like this:

```
onclick="alert('Ok, this is your last chance. Don\'t press anymore buttons... not that there are any')">NOT A BUTTON</button>
        </div>
</body>
```

Escape characters are used to remove the special meaning from a single character, and instead preserve the literal value. In this case, the quote within "Don't" was causing the program to read that as the end of the string, and ignore the rest of that line. That's why you got this error:

{
**"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",**
}